# Angularjs Service Injection Issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

I'm trying to add a service to my Angular project for the first time and running into issues injecting it within my controller.

I am getting an error of --
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined`

I'm looking to properly inject the service into the controller and ways I can improve the code for best practices/efficiency.
Thanks for the help!

I have a folder /event in my angular project with the following files --

`app.js
controllers.js
directives.js
services.js`

app.js file has --

```
'use strict';

angular.module('vyrt.event', [
  'vyrt.event.controllers',
  'vyrt.event.services',
  'vyrt.event.directives'
]);
```

services.js file has --

```
'use strict';

angular.module('vyrt.event.services', []).
service('VyrtEventService', ['$http', function($http) {
var artistId = 0,
  artist = '',
  events = [],
  active_event_idx = 0;

  this.get = function(artistId) {
    var url = '/api/users/' + artistId + '/';
    $http.get(url).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      artist = data.artist.user;
      events = data.artist.events;
      active_event_id = data.artist.events[0].id;
    });
    return artist, events, active_event_id;
  }
}]);
```

finally, the controller has --

```
'use strict';

angular.module('vyrt.event.controllers', []).
controller('VyrtEventCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope, VyrtEventService) {

  console.log(VyrtEventService.get($scope.artistId));

  $scope.activeCampaign = function(idx) {
    if (idx == VyrtEventService.active_event_idx) return true;
    return false;
  };
}]);
```

Comment: there is no benefit in creating a module just to create a service. Modules are usually used to group features together. Also you can't return data from a function that makes asynchronous call to get that data

Comment: thanks for the tips! in this case, we are grouping features together.

Comment: making extra modules just for the sake of it is just extra needless work such as `angular.module('vyrt.event.controllers', [])`. A new module is not needed fro every component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you've forgotten to put 'VyrtEventService' in your dependency list when you define you controller:

```
.controller('VyrtEventCtrl', ['$scope', /* you need this ==>*/ 'VyrtEventService', function($scope, VyrtEventService) {

    console.log('VyrtEventService', VyrtEventService);


    $scope.activeCampaign = function(idx) {
      if (idx == VyrtEventService.active_event_idx) return true;
      return false;
    };
  }]);
```

Update

Your `get()` function has a couple of issues. First, you need to return the `$http.get()` call itself and then you can call `then()` in your controller and set the results to a property on your `$scope` there. Second, you can't return multiple values like that. You would have to return an array of values or an object with your desired values assigned to it.

**service**

```
this.get = function(artistId) {
    var url = '/api/users/' + artistId + '/';

    return $http
        .get(url)
        .catch(function(error){
            // handle errors here
            console.log('Error fething artist data: ', error);
        });
  }
```

**controller**

```
VyrtEventService
    .get(artistId)
    .then(function(data){
        $scope.artist = data.artist.user;
        $scope.events = data.artist.events;
        $scope.active_event_id = data.artist.events[0].id;
    });

$scope.activeCampaign = function(idx) {
    return (idx == $scope.active_event_idx);
};
```

Comment: looks like i have a couple issues. now the issue seems to be returning the values of artist, events from the get api call to the controller

Comment: Yes you need to return the $http call itself and then set the results in your controller. I will update hold on.